# Trying to over-ride the title for a Web Part Document Library to a value in the URL - SharePoint 2016

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a custom page in SharePoint that I pass some URL Parameters that are used within as filters for document libraries that are displayed on the page.  There are three document library web parts on the page all accessing the same library, but are different views based on one of the three URL parameters as filters.  I would like to over-ride the Title of the web part to be that of the URL filter value.  Based on the other web parts on this page, I have the code that will identify the appropriate web parts, but I lack the code to over-ride the text.  The name of the document library is VirtualDocuments.  The variables currentName2, currentName3, and currentName4 refers back to the URL Parameters.

```
   $(".ms-webpart-titleText > a").each(function(i){
       switch(i) {
         case 4:
           $(".ms-webpart-chrome-title span:contains('EPMO')").currentName3;
           //$(this).css('color','i#8842d5');
           break;
         case 5:
           $(this).css('values',currentName3);
           $(this).css('color','i#8842d5');
           break;
         case 6:
           $(this).css('values',currentName4);
           $(this).css('color','i#8842d5');
      };
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code, just replace chrome title is with your webpart title id.

```
$("#WebPartWPQ6_ChromeTitle > #WebPartTitleWPQ6 > .ms-webpart-titleText ").text("Sample")
```

Comment: That works if I find the id of each webpart and in my case 10, 13, and 3 respectively.  However, the color seems to change to black.  How would I then change the color back to white?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to change the library webpart name based on the url parameter. You may insert some jquery/js code into script editor to change the dom:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tar= $(".ms-webpart-chrome-title span:contains('Documents')");
            var para = GetUrlKeyValue("currentName2",true,window.location.href);
            tar.text(para);
        });

</script>
```

BR